# Angular reverse engineering: Go back to component from listener (devTools > Elements > Event listeners) through Zone.js

Tags: javascript, angular, google-chrome-devtools, zone.js

I'm working on an angular (7.x) app running in dev mode.

Starting from browser (chrome in my case) `devTools` > `Elements` > `Event listeners`, is there a way to "easily" retrieve which angular component set the listener (inside template `(click)=call()` or using `renderer.listen()`) ?

[image]

We can see the handler is inside `zone.js` line 1551, function `globalZoneAwareCallback` but no trace about a component ref or name..

Comment: this is a great question, I will try to do some research to find out whether it is possible to extract the underlying information inside Chrome dev tool.

Comment: Nice, thank you. I've seen you are an 'angular collaborator' on twitter, felicitations! 

Answer (score 0):

Do you tried with https://augury.rangle.io/ ? I found it very useful

Comment: I've tried several times but not helpful for me (wrong `changeDetectionStrategy` displayed, missing `@Input`,..) and not working in application using wijmo lib..